# How do I get the height of a cube in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have the following code;

```
// World
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 200, 100 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 'green' } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.position.y = (cube.height / 2); // this doesn't work
scene.add( cube );
```

What is the correct method to get the height of the cube? I know the height = 100, but I want to understand how I get the height using program code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a cube mesh using `THREE.BoxGeometry`, you can get the height of the cube by accessing the `parameters` property of the geometry:

```
height = mesh.geometry.parameters.height;
```

If you have changed the mesh property `scale.y` from its default value of 1, then you will have to multiply the above quantity by `scale.y`.

three.js r.71

Answer (score 4):

The bounding box of an object will give its accurate dimensions:

```
var cube_bbox = new THREE.Box3();
cube_bbox.setFromObject( cube );
```

Now you have the vectors `cube_bbox.max` and `cube_bbox.min` so:

```
cube_height = cube_bbox.max.y - cube_bbox.min.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

The box Geometry object that you created has 3 properties (Height, Width and Depth). These 3 properties are read as x,y,z. As a result, if you want to change the height, you will have to change the Y axis.

```
geometry.scale.y = 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate it from geometry.

```
//you need to get correct verts 0 and 4 are for example
var height=cube.geometry.vertices[4].y-cube.geometry.vertices[0].y;
```